# VBA Access: declaring Public Type inside a class

Tags: vba, class, ms-access, generics, public

I have tried to **declare** a **public Type** inside a module class with no success.

As a private one there is no problem but there is no way to extract the content from the main module, so it has no sense for me.

Is there any way?

Comment: Could you place the Type in a Module instead of a Class?

Comment: If you're creating a class, the only public members should be the properties, functions and methods of the class. If you need to access a value from a class, then just make that value into a public property.

Comment: I haven't found a place where access can't see public functions.  So make synthetic properties with public functions is my standard approach.  In other words make public functions called setPropertyName and getPropertyName.  For example, in a textbox afterUpdate event call setThatPropertyName and in a query call getThatPropertyName.

Comment: Classes need instances so it must be declared in a standard module. Once declared in a standard module, you can have a property of the type in your class.

Comment: Ok, it is not exactly what I am looking for, but it works. Fine, thnx all guys